# Как заменить все заглавные буквы в строке на строчные?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью javascript (возможно jQuery) привести строку вида "СлОн" к "слон"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `toLowerCase()`

Данный метод преобразует все буквы в строке к нижнему регистру.
Метод `toLowerCase` не применяется к знакам, отличным от букв.
В следующем примере демонстрируется действие метода `toLowerCase`

```
var text = "This is a STRING.";
var str = text. toLowerCase();
document.write(str);
```

На `jQuery` это можно сделать примерно так

```
$('input#email').val($(this).val().toLowerCase());
```